# Yandex.Browser QuickLinks

Tags: javascript, html, seo, yandex

We have already have a web site. Let's say www.mysite.com. When you open this site at *yandex.browser* at right hand side there are some quicklinks. (screenshot below)

[image]

Now we are developing a new website and we are in testing phase. We informed some of our customers and say *come to new site and test it*. Its web address is beta.mysite.com.

Our problem is that when they come to new site (beta.mysite.com) by *yandex.browser* at right hand side quicklinks appears  automatically but their targets are wrong! Their targets show old site.(www.mysite.com)

- Can we change their targets by modifying our beta.mysite.com headers or html? How?

OR

- Can we disable quicklinks at yandex.browser by modifying our beta.mysite.com html code?

I don't want to affect www.mysite.com. My purpose is to fix for beta.mysite.com

Comment: Don't know much about yandex.browser so can you tell me how did you define them at first place?

Comment: As i understand, your question is how did you define that links at old web site (www.mysite.com)? I didn't define them. Maybe previous developers defined them to yandex. I don't know anything about yandex services and yandex procedures to register a website to them. I will investigate this possibility  in the company today.

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm asking. You can set a logo in address bar but to set a link is something new for me. Also why would you want to set a link in address bar? Do you seriously expect someone to look at address bar for possible links? :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `head` tag

```
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive"/>
```

this will suggest (or even force) retrieval of updated links (that is, which are not cached). You can read more about it here - [controlling-robot](https://help.yandex.com/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.xml).

Comment: Hi Divya, first of all thanks for quick reply. :) I added meta tag into head as you declared. But nothing changed. Your link (controlling - robot) is about yandex search engine  robot and i think, that change will affect only search results at yandex. But my problem is about yandex.browser. You can visit http://beta.kitapyurdu.com with yandex.browser and see the problem. If you look at page source you will see that i applied your suggestion, but at right hand side the old web site quick links exists. (payment,delivery,basket)

Comment: Browsers can cache a search result but i doubt they will cache a link address.

Comment: Hi Mandeep, I have cleared browser cache (from beginning of time) after update. But result is the same.